# Make switch case detect characters and input them into an array

Tags: java, switch-statement

Not sure if the switch is what's causing the problem, but this switch is supposed to convert Latin characters into its Cyrillic "form". It seems to go to the default switch every time.

Also unsure whether inputting the parameter as a String.toCharArray() causes problems

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
cyr("abcekmh".toLowerCase().toCharArray());
}
private static void cyr(char[] c) {
           char[] d = new char[c.length];
           for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
               switch((char)c[i]) {
               case 'a':
                   d[i] = 'а';
               case 'b':
                   d[i] = 'в';
               case 'e':
                   d[i] = 'е';
               case 'k':
                   d[i] = 'к';
               case 'm':
                   d[i] = 'м';
               case 'h':
                   d[i] = 'н';
               case 'i':
                   d[i] = 'ı';
               case 'o':
                   d[i] = 'о';
               case 'p':
                   d[i] = 'р';
               case 'c':
                   d[i] = 'с';
               case 't':
                   d[i] = 'т';
               case 'y':
                   d[i] = 'у';
               case 'x':
                   d[i] = 'х';
               default:
                   d[i] = c[i];
               }
           }
           for(char russian : d) {
               System.out.print(russian);
           }
       }
```

Comment: [The Java Tutorials - The switch Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html): **"Another point of interest is the break statement. Each break statement terminates the enclosing switch statement. Control flow continues with the first statement following the switch block. The break statements are necessary because without them, statements in switch blocks fall through: All statements after the matching case label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of subsequent case labels, until a break statement is encountered. "**

Comment: You also just use a `Map` for this, and make it way simpler

Comment: Off Topic: In my opinion, using `switch` / `case` isn't the best way to transliterate letters from one alphabet to another. I suggest a translation table or, as a previous comment said, a `Map`.  Also, double check your transliteration code. The code you have has some errors.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer Thank you for the response! May I ask where I could find documentation/links about java translation tables? I haven't been able to find anything related to them

Comment: @gooooodmorning  May I suggest you post another question?  Ask about transliterating letters from one alphabet to another in the header. In the body, include a copy of this code, with `break` statements, and ask for a "cleaner" way to code transliteration. Some will suggest using a `Map`, which is a better idea. If I see it, I'll try to suggest how a table might be used.

Comment: I don't know that there is any standard method for this in Java and Unicode. I was thinking we'd have to work it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is missing the `break` statement at the end of a case block. Without `break` you get a fall through to the next case/default.

See [The switch Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) documentation.